# Creating a gradient from the colors of a photo using ImageMagick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick

I've been searching for a minute now on whether this was possible but haven't had any luck. My goal is to save the gradient values from an image in the form of an array. So far I've seen examples to get dominant colors of an image. Can I achieve this from the backend without using a client-side script?

Comment: Please show an example. P.S. searching for only one minute is awfully short a search time :)

Comment: An example of retrieving the dominant colors?

Comment: What do you mean by gradient? Gradient in color or derivative gradient?

Comment: A gradient in color.

Comment: Reduce the image to 256 colors and then sort as desired. Then graph them. See my script, dominantcolor on my web site in my profile. Also see +dither -colors 256

Comment: Great. Your script is exactly what I was looking for. Feel free to post this as an answer. Thanks for the tip.